# Removing last character from a variable in a Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to assign a value to a variable called "doNotLog" based on the last character of some other variable called "choice" through a Batch file.

The structure of the variable choice is:

1) Either an integer with 1 or more digits

2) Or an integer with 1 or more digits plus character "n" at the last

The objectives are:

1) To set the value of "doNotLog" to true if the last character of "choice" is n

2) To finally remove n from "choice"

The Batch file I'm using to achieve this is:

```
@echo off

echo enter choice
set/p choice=
set doNotLog=false

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
if %choice:~-1,1%==n ( 
    set doNotLog=true
    set choice=!choice:n=!
)
endlocal

echo After changes:
echo choice=  %choice%
echo donotLog=  %doNotLog%

@pause
```

It produces the following output:

```
enter choice
54n
After changes:
choice=  54n
donotLog=  false
Press any key to continue . . .
```

However, I was expecting the following output:

```
enter choice
54n
After changes:
choice=  54
donotLog=  true
Press any key to continue . . .
```

How do I achieve my desired output

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Comment: The `endlocal` dismisses all preceding variable changes, so move the `echo` commands before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you've tried to modify `doNotLog` and `choice` inside a [`setlocal`](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html), so you've set them locally, but the global ones remain unchanged.

---

Get the value of them inside `setlocal` to achieve the expected result:

```
@echo off

echo enter choice
set/p choice=
set doNotLog=false

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
if %choice:~-1,1%==n ( 
    set doNotLog=true
    set choice=!choice:n=!
)

echo After changes:
echo choice=  %choice%
echo donotLog=  %doNotLog%

@pause

endlocal
```

If you want to disable the delayed expansion anyway, you can put the rest of the code in *another `setlocal`*, that disables it:

```
@echo off

echo enter choice
set/p choice=
set doNotLog=false

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
if %choice:~-1,1%==n ( 
    set doNotLog=true
    set choice=!choice:n=!
)
setlocal DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

echo After changes:
echo choice=  %choice%
echo donotLog=  %doNotLog%

@pause

:: We have to end two locals now...
endlocal
endlocal
```

...however, if you do this multiple times, your code will quickly become unmaintainable (oh, wait, aren't *all* batch files unmaintainable?) and less performant.

---

Alternatively, you can move variables out of local by using the magic of single-line or parenthesis-grouped commands, and the classic `%variable%` syntax:

```
endlocal & set "doNotLog=%doNotLog%" & set "choice=%choice%"
```

...or the equivalent, but more readable...

```
(
    endlocal
    set "doNotLog=%doNotLog%"
    set "choice=%choice%"
)
```

The above solutions might look silly, but they do work...

Both of the above will set global variables, because they're after `endlocal`, but read the local ones, as they're substituted before the evaluation of the line (or the grouped structure) starts. (That's why these hacks work with the `%var%` syntax, but not with the `!var!`)

So, your code can even be changed to:

```
@echo off

echo enter choice
set/p choice=
set doNotLog=false

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
if %choice:~-1,1%==n ( 
    set doNotLog=true
    set choice=!choice:n=!
)
endlocal & (
    set "doNotLog=%doNotLog%"
    set "choice=%choice%"
)

echo After changes:
echo choice=  %choice%
echo donotLog=  %doNotLog%

@pause
```

...which may be the best solution among these.

Answer (score 4):

Variable expansion is described under the help information for the `Set` command. Open a Command Prompt window and enter `set /?` to read it.

Here's some helper examples for you:

```
C:\Users\Mohd>Set "Variable=String"

C:\Users\Mohd>Echo(%Variable%
String

C:\Users\Mohd>Echo(%Variable:~0,-1%
Strin

C:\Users\Mohd>Echo(%Variable:~0,1%
tring

C:\Users\Mohd>Echo(%Variable:~0,-2%
Stri

C:\Users\Mohd>Echo(%Variable:~-1,1%
g

C:\Users\Mohd>Echo(%Variable:~1,-1%
trin

C:\Users\Mohd>Echo(%Variable:~1,1%
t

C:\Users\Mohd>Echo(%Variable:~1,2%
tr

C:\Users\Mohd>Echo(%Variable:~1,-2%
tri

C:\Users\Mohd>Echo(%Variable:~2,1%
r

C:\Users\Mohd>Echo(%Variable:~2,-1%
rin

C:\Users\Mohd>Echo(%Variable:~2,-2%
ri

C:\Users\Mohd>Echo(%Variable:~-2,2%
ng

C:\Users\Mohd>Echo(%Variable:~-2,1%
n

C:\Users\Mohd>Echo(%Variable:~2,-3%
r
```

Answer (score 0):

---

So, what about without using **`SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion`**

```bat
@echo off 

set "doNotLog=" && set "choice="
for /f ^skip^=^4 %%a in ('echo/ prompt $h^| cmd
')do echo/ && set/p "choice=-%%a Enter choice: "

echo/%choice:~-1%|find /i "n">nul && (
call set "choice=%choice:~0,-1%" && set "doNotLog=true")

if "%doNotLog%" == "" set "doNotLog=false"
echo/ choice = %choice% && echo/ doNotLog = %doNotLog% 
echo/ Press any key to continue... & timeout -1 >nulF
```

---

- outputs for input **`54n`** and **`54`**  ::

  ---

```bat
G:\SO_en-EN\Q59738810>Q59738810.cmd

 Enter choice: 54n
 choice = 54
 doNotLog = true
 Press any key to continue...

---------------------------------------

G:\SO_en-EN\Q59738810>Q59738810.cmd

 Enter choice: 54
 choice = 54
 doNotLog = false
 Press any key to continue...
```

---